# How can you set up a secondary/backup proxy in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, proxy

I am working on a asp.net mvc application that requires a proxy in order to send emails. The < defaultProxy > has been successfully set up in the < system.net > section of the web.config file and works as expected.

Unfortunately there have been some issues with the proxy itself failing and therefore critical emails have failed to send. On each occasion a fix for the proxy has been found, but that does not negate the fact that important emails have not been sent.

Is it possible to define a backup alternative proxy to be used by the application in the event that the default proxy fails?

Comment: A better way is to handle the failure case and make the application to retry after some interval.

Comment: Thanks @Thangadurai, we have planned to implement the application retrying to send the emails but there isn't 24/7 support for the proxy so emails will continue to fail without a backup proxy to try until the proxy issue is resolved the next day